# Each ajax calls to mvc.net controller creates a separate session

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an asp.net mvc application and I have some JavaScript that calls the same Controller several times with different parameters, and for each ajax call I can see that `onSession start` is getting fired.

How can I have a session maintained for the multiple ajax calls coming from the same client?

Comment: Aren't you using a short session lifetime? Is your session identifier cookie being sent with each ajax call? Is your `"Session Namespace"` empty? (meaning have you set any variable in your session)? It's likely that mvc.net is creating new sessions (generating new ID) for every "empty" session

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the issue is with cookie as you mention i had to enable cookie (cookiles on session attribute to be false)